# Kafka streams threads and count of records being processed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Say we have a Topic with 2 partitions and there are 'n' no of producers which are producing the data to this Topic. Now, Millions of the MessageRecords are being spread over 2 partitions.

Say, we have 2 threads (i.e. 2 separate Instances) powering to the Streams Processor.  Now, In this setup, say Thread-1(i.e. Streaming Task-1) got Partition P-1 and say Thread-2(i.e. Streaming Task-2) got Partition P-2 for processing !!

ASK is :- Say, we want to know, how many `MessageRecords` have been processed by Streaming-Task-1 so far  OR say for 28th September, 2KK ?? How do I do that ?

And, even the bigger the question is : "Streaming-Task-1" would never know about the TOTAL count of `MessageRecords` being processed, it shall only know about the count processed by itself !!

Can it ever know it know about the count processed by another Task-2 ??

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish what you are asking. If you are using the DSL I suggest you take a look at the word count example (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/quickstart.html). With a map operation you can make all the counts you want relatively simply.

If you are not using the dsl you can still do the same with a couple processors and state stores.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went through the highlighted link and I have a doubt. This way, each Stream-Procssing-Task would be calculating the count of records processed by that task ONLY. I want to know the TOTAL count of records !! Because the KTable being created is local to that streaming task only. Right ?? How to solve that !!

Comment: Global counting is hard. You could do it in a two step approach: do local counting, and than write the result of both partial counts into a single-partitioned topic and sum up the counts.